# Mongodb installation

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

Mongodb installed in linux CentOS server (ssh) with steps mentioned in this url

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Started MongoDB server using the command and the status is ok.

```
sudo service mongod start 

When connecting mongodb with PHP (Yii app), it shows error like this.
include(MongoClient.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

PHP code

<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->health;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->medical;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Yii2` provide class `yii\mongodb\Connection` for mongodb connection.

Check below link.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-connection.html

**MongoDb Extension for Yii 2**

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: If my answer is working for you then mark it as correct to help other people facing same issue. glad to help.